# List terms and order by second word

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have the following code in my sidebar listing the terms or a custom taxonomy, these are names, first Name and last name. Is it possible to list them alphabetically by last name rather than the first name?

Thanks

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'name';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {

echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '"title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' .    $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too specific of a condition for there to be a native way.

On other hand this is hardly complicated as simply sorting an array in PHP. You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a small custom callback, containing your comparison logic.